# How to set notification in my custom date and time

Tags: java, android

I want to add notification on custom date and time in my todo app so that it can notify me on the time which i set . Please help me to add notification in my app. I want to get reminder for my todo application on the specific date and time.

```java
private void showDateTimeDialog(final EditText date_time_in) {
    final Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,dayOfMonth);

            TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeSetListener=new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hourOfDay);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);

                    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMM yyyy" +" "+ "hh:mm"+" "+"a");

                    date_time_in.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
                }
            };

            new TimePickerDialog(AddEditTaskActivity.this,timeSetListener,calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),false).show();
        }
    };

    new DatePickerDialog(AddEditTaskActivity.this,dateSetListener,calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();

}

private void showTimeDialog(final EditText time_in) {
    final Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();

    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeSetListener=new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hourOfDay);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm" + " " + "a");
            time_in.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
        }
    };
    new TimePickerDialog(AddEditTaskActivity.this,timeSetListener,calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),false).show();
}

private void showDateDialog(final EditText date_in) {
    final Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,dayOfMonth);
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            date_in.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
        }
    };
    new DatePickerDialog(AddEditTaskActivity.this,dateSetListener,calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely need to implement an Alarm Manager to create notifications according to the time set.
You can find more about it here:

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_notifications.htm